# J Query, CSS, themeroller not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, themeroller

I am trying to link the style sheet using the theme i created on theme roller but when i added the links into my html code the theme does not load. The theme which i have selected is theme a, so i dont think it is that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Games</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/mobileapp.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Homepage -->

<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Games</h1>
</div>

<div role="main" class="ui-content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#games">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#where">Where we Are</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your theme last, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/mobileapp.min.css" />
```

Putting it first means that the default theme overrides yours. You want it the other way around.